# Flagging: How to use "Not an answer" or "Low Quality"

Tags: discussion, flagging

Recently I flagged some of the answers and flags got declined saying

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer

So my question is how can I use flags like "Not an answer" or "Low Quality answer"

Few examples:

[The web application at [url] could not be found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20690/the-web-application-at-url-could-not-be-found/91368#91368)

[Site Contents link in Quick Launch below Edit link (SharePoint 2013)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91517/site-contents-link-in-quick-launch-below-edit-link-sharepoint-2013/91536#91536)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Low quality answer** should be used to flag answers that contains very little information (for example "link-only-answers")

  > This question/answer has severe formatting or content problems. This
  >   question/answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and
  >   might need to be removed.

  More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606)
- **Not an answer** should be used for answers that is not answers, e.g. comments on other answers, spam, or other nonsense posts.

  > - The OP...
  >
  >   - needed to update the question with new information, but posted the new information as an answer.
  >   - wanted to reply to an existing comment or answer, but posted the reply as an answer.
  >   - posted a "resolution answer" saying something along the lines of "Joe's answer worked for me"
  > - A user...
  >
  >   - wants to reply to the OP, an answerer or a commenter, but doesn't have enough rep, and instead of thinking "maybe there's a
  >       reason I'm not allowed to post comments," ignores the help text about
  >       what an answer is.
  >   - posts to say "I'm having this problem too, does anyone have a solution yet?"
  >   - has a related issue and isn't aware of the "Ask Question" button.

  More [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81389/when-should-you-decide-whether-to-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/81392#81392)

We decline flags where there is a valid answer posted (correct or completely wrong does not matter, we look only on the structure of the answer and checks that it is not spam, or personal attacks etc.).

If you find an answer to be wrong, you should use the power of [**Downvoting**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) (yes you will lose 1 rep, but hey you will help the community content to keep a high quality) to send the message to the user and to future readers.

Comment: I totally agree +1